# Uniqueness of product in the category of Sets

Tags: category-theory, products

I understand why the Cartesian product $A \times B$ is the product of $A$ and $B$ in the category of sets. But is it the only product from the point of view of the category theory? Following the categorical definition, product is defined up to an isomorphism and there can be more than one product.

I think $B \times A$ is another product (and there is a bijection between $B\times A$ and $A \times B$). Am I right? Are there any other products?

Comment: If $A \cong A'$ and $B \cong B'$, $A' \times B'$ is another product of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Yes, indeed $B\times A$ is a product of $A,B$. In general, if there is an isomorphism $\phi:P\rightarrow A\times B$ (that is, a 1-1 onto function), then $P$, with projections $\pi_0\phi:P\rightarrow A$ and $\pi_1\phi:P\rightarrow B$, is the product of $A,B$

Comment: Thank you very much; now I understand. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

In category theory, a product of $A$ and $B$ is not merely an object, but rather it is an object $P$ *together with* two morphism $\pi_A\colon P\to A$ and $\pi_B\colon P\to B$, called the "projections", that satisfy the universal property associated to the product.

The universal property ensures that if $(P,\pi_A,\pi_B)$ is a product, and $(R,\rho_A,\rho_B)$ is also a product, then there exists a unique isomorphism $\phi\colon P\to R$ such that $\pi_A = \rho_A\circ \phi$ and $\pi_B=\rho_B\circ\phi$. So we say the product is "unique up to unique isomorphism", but that uniqueness requires you to have the full information about the product: the object and the projection morphisms.

Conversely, if $Q$ is any object and $\psi\colon P\to Q$ is an isomorphism, then we can make $Q$ into a product of $A$ and $B$ by defining $q_A\colon Q\to A$ to be $q_A=\pi_A\circ\psi^{-1}$ and $q_B=\pi_B\circ\psi^{-1}$.

So, in your case, yes: $A\times B$ with $\pi_A(a,b)=a$ and $\pi_B(a,b)=b$ is a product of $A$ and $B$. Also, $B\times A$ with $\pi_A(b,a)=a$ and $\pi_B(b,a)=b$, is another product. And any set that can be bijected with $A\times B$ can be given the structure of a product by defining suitable "projection functions".

(The above holds for any family of objects, not just pairs)

Comment: In other words, if $A$ is a set with $n$ elements and $B$ is a set with $m$ elements, *any* set with $nm$ elements can serve as a product of $A$ and $B$. The cartesian product $A \times B$ is just one of (class) many examples.

Comment: Thank you very much for such an elaborate answer. You already answered the second question I wanted to ask: every product (defined categorically by that universal property) defines a partition of its codomain? Following your point, the answer is yes. 
Every triple (P, pi_a, pi_b) gives rise to an equivalence relation on the codomain of the product. “A” product, along with all of the members isomorphic to it, comprise one of the two equivalence classes in the codomain.

Comment: I think the converse of the above mentioned (previous comment) statement is not necessarily true: every isomorphism class (in codomain) does not define a product (P, pi_a, pi_b). Why? Because the suitable projection morphisms may not exist.

Comment: @AliKoohpaee: I”m sorry, but *what* “codomain of the product”? The product is an object, and two/family of functions with domain $P$. There is no single codomain: each of the projections has a different codomain. I don’t understand anything you say in your comments, because it refers to something that does not exist. I have no idea what you think “codomain [of the product]” means. It means nothing to me.

Comment: Dear Arturo, thanks for your comment. Yes, I did not use the correct term. You are right. Product is an object. What I meant by "codomain" was the category that the object belongs to. For instance, in the case of Cartesian product of the sets, the category which "the product" belongs to is the category of Sets. The equivalence relation that I was talking about, defines a partion of the category of Sets (i.e. the class of objects of the category of Sets). Am I right?

Comment: @AliKoohpaee What equivalence do you think the product defines? In any category, you have the notion of “isomorphism” and there is a categorical notion “capturing” the idea of isomorphism classes (it’s called a “skeleton” of the category). In general you can’t treat it like you do a set because the collection of objects of a category need not be a set (depending on your formalization). In **any** category, any object isomorphic to a universal object can be made into an instance of the universal object, and every instance of the universal object is isomorphic to any other. What is your point?

Comment: @AliKoohpaee: As the answer itself points out: if $X$ is **any** set isomorphic to the product object $P$, via an isomorphism $\phi\colon P\to X$, then you can turn $X$ into a product by defining the projections by $\xi_A\colon X\to A$ to be $\xi_A = \pi_A\circ \phi$, and $\xi_B=\pi_B\circ \phi$. So the “converse” (every object isomorphic to $P$ can be made into a product) is absolutely, completely, definitely **true**.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: Dear Arturo, thank you very much for your illuminating comments. It took a few days for me to think to them and read about the concept of product. Thank you for recalling the notion of "skeleton"; I think now I can express more precisely what I had in my mind. Suppose that we have a category $C$ and that the triple $(P, \pi_a, \pi_b)$ is a product (i.e. P is an object of $C$ and $\pi_a$ and $\pi_b$ are two morphism satisfying the universal property associated with the product. Also to put it precisely, $a$ and $b$ are codomain of the morphisms $\pi_a$ and $\pi_b$ ...

Comment: ... respectively. Then $P$ is "a product" of $a$ and $b$). Now, what happens if $C$ is a skeletal category? Then, $P$ will be the only object of $C$ that satisfies the universal property: the product will be unique. In this case, there will be a one to one relation between triples $(P, \pi_a, \pi_b)$ and "the" product (which is an object of $C$). Now, my point is that such a one to one relation allows us to "identify" certain members of $C$ with triples $(P, \pi_a, \pi_b)$. My second point: do we have such an identification for all of the objects of $C$? My answer is No. Why? Because not ...

Comment: ... all the objects of $C$ need to satisfy the universal property for some $(P,\pi_a,\pi_b)$. I think there would be a more abstract description of this issue if we could describe product in terms of a functor (Then we would study when such a functor is full or faithful). I could not yet do so.

Comment: @AliKoohpaee: Sorry, but is there a question, or are you simply using the comment thread to pontificate?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin:Following the previous comment: What happens if the category $C$ is not skeletal? Then not certain objects of $C$, but certain isomorphism classes of $C$ will be in one to one correspondence with triples $(P,\pi_a,\pi_b)$. This is what I meant by "defining a partition" on $C$: for each triple $(P,\pi_a,\pi_b)$ we will have an isomorphism class.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: In response to your previous comment: No sir; absolutely not. I apologize if my acts have resulted in any inconvenience.

Comment: @AliKoohpaee: No, you aren't asking a question? Then kindly remove your comments; this is not a blog. It's not a place for you to "think out loud" or to express your thoughts about a subject.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: what I wrote was in response to your question: “what’s your point?”. Now if you think they are irrelevant, I will remove them for sure.

Comment: @AliKoohpaee: Let me ask you again: is your long comment and its two continuations actually asking a question? If you are not asking a question, if all you are doing is trying to make a point that is not directly relevant to the answer or to your original question, then they don't belong here: they are just a threaded blog post. Right now, that's what they look like: they look like you thinking out loud using the original question and answer as a jumping-off point. That's not a comment, that's a blog post.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: Dear Arturo, I thank you for your illuminating comment. I understand your point. To my eyes, what I have written is not merely thinking aloud. Those comments elaborate on the questions I asked earlier. I think retaining them would better than deleting them. However, I understand your point that this is not the right place for thinking aloud. I will try to do better in the future. Thanks again for your illuminating comments.

Answer (score 1):

This was briefly mentioned in Arturo's answer, but let me spell it out more fully.

Let $A$, $B$ and $P$ be sets and suppose that $f : P \cong A \times B$. Define $p_1: P \to A$ by $\pi_1 \circ f$ and $p_2 : P \to B$ by $\pi_2 \circ f$. I claim that $(P, p_1, p_2)$ is a categorical product of $A$ and $B$.

First, $p_1$ and $p_2$ give the necessary projections. For the universal property, let $h : S \to A$ and $k : S \to B$ be any functions (for any set $S$). We want to prove that there is a unique function $u: S \to P$ such that $p_1 \circ u = h$ and $p_2 \circ u = k$. By the universal property for the ordinary product, (h, k) is the unique function $S \to A \times B$ such that $\pi_1 \circ (h, k) = h$ and $\pi_2 \circ (h, k) = k$. Since $f$ is an isomorphism, this implies that $u = f^{-1} \circ (h, k)$ is the unique function such that $\pi_1 \circ f \circ u = h$ and $\pi_2 \circ f \circ u = k$. But that means that $u$ is the unique map we wanted, since $\pi_i \circ f = p_i$.

So in a sense, $A \times B$ is maximally non-unique: any set with the right cardinality can be made to work. But on the other hand, any such set is of the form above, meaning that the projection functions for one product are equal to the projection functions for the other product composed with an isomorphism between the two objects. This follows from the universal property. Phrased differently, any two products are isomorphic via a unique isomorphism that commutes with the projections.

Comment: Thank you very much for such an elaborate answer. Now, I understand.